# Create different related records on a single page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'd like to create a VF page that creates two different records from two different custom objects. These objects have a master-detail relationship between one another. Custom_Object_B is the detail. This is what I have so far, but I'm getting an error.

> Invalid field Custom_Object_B__r for SObject Custom_Object_A__c

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Custom_Object_A__c">
    <apex:form>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Create Two New Records"> 

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{! Custom_Object_A__c.Name}"/>      
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{! Custom_Object_A__c.Custom_Object_B__r.Name}"/>      
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />        
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: May be you first need to insert a Master record and then you can insert a child records. The above error is causing as your instance object has been changed to __r. It should be __c being its as standard controller.

Comment: To fix your error change  Custom_Object_A__r.Custom_Object_B__c.Name to Custom_Object_A__c.Custom_Object_B__r.Name (when adding __r the plural name of the object has to be used) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Comment: @Rao done, now I get Invalid field Custom_Object_B__r for Custom_Object_A__c

Comment: Do you have a lookup field on custom object A referencing custom object B? What is the plural name of the custom object B, append a __r after the plural name

Comment: @Rao As stated in my original question, I have a master-detail relationship (field),  which is on the Custom_Object_B.

Comment: I have done this with related records, but I use a custom controller.  I first create the parent record.  Then I create the child record.   Master-detail should be similar.  I don't know how to do this with a standard controller.

Comment: @Jagular is using the standardController a bad idea? All I want is to create two different records that are related. Since this is the case, I don't see why you'd need to make a custom controller

Comment: @TylerZika __r can be used only when you are referencing child-to-parent, in your case the standardcontroller is on custom object A(parent), you are trying to use Parent-to-child for which you will have to query the data. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Comment: @Rao The records don't exist though, I'm creating them on the page, so there is nothing to query. Do I need to use an extension?

Comment: Come to this chat room : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46437/parent-child

Comment: Looks like you're working on a way to do this with a controller extension.  Could one of you please post it as an answer when it's complete?

Comment: @Jagular yeah I got an answer,  just waiting to see if he wants to post it for credit. If not I will post answer.